# Html link phone number detect if application is installed

Tags: html, response, skype, phone-number

If I link a phone number with HTML like this:

```
<a href="tel:123456789">123456789</a>
```

The Browser gives me a response if I want to start an application, in my case Skype.

Now my question, is it possible to create a selfmade window and tell something like download and install Skype if none suitable application like Skype to use that functionality is installed.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.  Which program is used to open a resource is solely at the discretion of the user's browser/computer.  There is (and should be) no way to interfere with that.  It would cause terrible security problems if a webpage had the ability to direct a browser towards a certain program or register if a specific program is installed.

Comment: No I do not want to direct I just want to say, that the user needs to install Skype or something to usse that functionality.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.  Do you want a modal window to pop up if a user clicks the link, informing them that they should have Skype (or something similar) installed  if they want to use this link?  That would be done every time the user clicks, even if they have Skype installed already.  Look into modal windows with JavaScript if that's what you are after.

Comment: yes, but only with a case to check if this window message pops up or any application is installed that uses that functionality.

Comment: Please read the last sentence of my answer again.  One cannot. Sorry.